# For loop while using scrapy

Tags: for-loop, scrapy

I am trying to crawl a website. I want to do it for different dates. So i am storing date in a list. But while trying to access items of list, crawler works only for 1st value in list. Please help. following is my code:

```
class SpidyQuotesViewStateSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'retail_price'

    def start_requests(self):
        print "start request"
        urls = "http://fcainfoweb.nic.in/PMSver2/Reports/Report_Menu_web.aspx"  

        yield scrapy.Request(url=urls, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        dated = ["05/03/2017","04/03/2017"]
        urls = "http://fcainfoweb.nic.in/PMSver2/Reports/Report_Menu_web.aspx"
        #frmdata = 
        cookies1 ={}
        val = response.headers.getlist('Set-Cookie')
        print "login session values" ,response.headers.getlist('Set-Cookie')
        if(len(val) != 0):
            cookies1['ASP.NET_SessionId'] = str(response.headers.getlist('Set-Cookie')[0].split(";")[0].split("=")[1])
            cookies1['path'] = str(response.headers.getlist('Set-Cookie')[0].split(";")[1].split("=")[1])
        print cookies1;
        for i in range(len(dated)):
            yield scrapy.FormRequest(url=urls, callback=self.parse1, formdata={'ctl00$MainContent$btn_getdata1':"Get Data",
            'ctl00$MainContent$Txt_FrmDate':dated[i],
            'ctl00$MainContent$Ddl_Rpt_Option0':"Daily Prices",
            'ctl00$MainContent$Rbl_Rpt_type':"Price report",
            'ctl00$MainContent$ddl_Language':"English",
            'ctl00$MainContent$Ddl_Rpt_type':"Retail", 
            '__EVENTVALIDATION':"IwZyKgfTXVzxiHxiPXGk/W8XQZBDb0EOPxJh6s8hofq0ffqOpiHSH77CafcxySF3PbkYgSMNFCJhLM2cGnL6SxT0PJuGDCJtV0V8Y4a94UErUCiSANiin+4uKckk9v9Ux8JqTVeaipppmlH+wyks2U9SgPfkNUsqw4eHCkDyB5akNNZImRIixOHHVY3JSXGkwXn7ueK9w+AgnqJzpXaWdMr9J1++M4VAFImSNF8brFSfPHe5kb/qzkGIwUr/KRouaRYK8WLWZh/Mbl9xwREwhDSxWJSOdihSE0WWoaqSMtpaR99rDDCsD3mdJqfu0aPIlREupTZRzlrmztXU0eS3949YW+ywdTRvykaMNgOW2Q4saYP5j/niKbRW6GiDnaLV2A38X/HW80+trrsjwJr9tjTKVFyikf6s/3gzyiTp11ivSkwIY2b3hutjYn7OfTDo",
            #'__EVENTVALIDATION':"HqVo2xHk04clYwnBposXbZGhbIr181A7RbyeZv74Cia7rXSKmpOpbeSnn3XXnoDJKRxMK0W9nxKZFfkNje+P/K7gE5HVjHJr9Gr0Gs46TntzKDsvzyii8jZ7e0fdZgQCJKoXxQNgR2vNkWqChKcEldBuMHCOgJRqCNCF/JPFKpdKZoIWr7GU8rhzwLijf/Gkm+FuTULs/fl2HHK6Z1QQEozzEHFsDwzl0G4IiN//eNYfHuUBXKZ3wdZzPqG0s53WHEuSBzhqBC9AtCJOs4ZZhdtwFh8iyTJ4PlsLP9DLHYHRCOAd72UO0UH8gT7gAkKVo1I4L540DilowOR9SttH7MM/oOs9qhKlnG61FgqkYGW8zGzF/yNEXO+beVAK1RVvuO+FDnuq/g36TRnUieei5GpAZ+96CSoCIxykdvHx8R+smTNF/5erlowV4ci+tcI7", 
            '__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED':"", 
            '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR':"85862B00",
            '__VIEWSTATE':"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", 
            #'__VIEWSTATE':"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", 
            '__LASTFOCUS':"", 
            '__EVENTARGUMENT':"", 
            '__EVENTTARGET':"", 
            'ctl00_MainContent_ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField':";;AjaxControlToolkit,+Version=4.1.51116.0,+Culture=neutral,+PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e:en-US:fd384f95-1b49-47cf-9b47-2fa2a921a36a:475a4ef5:addc6819:5546a2b:d2e10b12:effe2a26:37e2e5c9:5a682656:c7029a2:e9e598a9"},method='POST',cookies = cookies1)

    def parse1(self, response):
        path1 = "id('Panel1')"
        value1 = response.xpath(path1).extract_first()
        print value1
```

Comment: please share your spider logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are sending the spider more time on the same site, though with different form parameters. You have therefore to use `dont_filter=True` in the request, otherwise Scrapy blocks duplicate calls.

Then it seems to me that the site you are scraping don't allow you to make more than one request during the same session. Try for example to go to http://fcainfoweb.nic.in/PMSver2/Reports/Report_Menu_web.aspx with your browser, compile the form, get the data and than to go back to the initial page: It's impossible. So you have to modify your spider. Here's a very rough code just to give an idea. It works for me, but please don't use it in production!

```
class SpidyQuotesViewStateSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'retail_price'
    urls = "http://fcainfoweb.nic.in/PMSver2/Reports/Report_Menu_web.aspx"

    def start_requests(self):
        dated = ["01/03/2017","05/03/2017","04/03/2017"]
        for i in dated:
            request = scrapy.Request(url=self.urls, dont_filter=True, callback=self.parse)
            request.meta['question'] = i
            yield request

    def parse(self, response):
        thedate = response.meta['question']
        cookies1 ={}
        val = response.headers.getlist('Set-Cookie')
        print("login session values" ,response.headers.getlist('Set-Cookie'))
        if(len(val) != 0):
            cookies1['ASP.NET_SessionId'] = str(str(response.headers.getlist('Set-Cookie')[0]).split(";")[0].split("=")[1])
            cookies1['path'] = str(str(response.headers.getlist('Set-Cookie')[0]).split(";")[1].split("=")[1])

        yield scrapy.FormRequest(url=self.urls, dont_filter=True, callback=self.parse1, formdata={'ctl00$MainContent$btn_getdata1':"Get Data",
        'ctl00$MainContent$Txt_FrmDate': thedate,
        'ctl00$MainContent$Ddl_Rpt_Option0':"Daily Prices",
        'ctl00$MainContent$Rbl_Rpt_type':"Price report",
        'ctl00$MainContent$ddl_Language':"English",
        'ctl00$MainContent$Ddl_Rpt_type':"Retail", 
        '__EVENTVALIDATION':"IwZyKgfTXVzxiHxiPXGk/W8XQZBDb0EOPxJh6s8hofq0ffqOpiHSH77CafcxySF3PbkYgSMNFCJhLM2cGnL6SxT0PJuGDCJtV0V8Y4a94UErUCiSANiin+4uKckk9v9Ux8JqTVeaipppmlH+wyks2U9SgPfkNUsqw4eHCkDyB5akNNZImRIixOHHVY3JSXGkwXn7ueK9w+AgnqJzpXaWdMr9J1++M4VAFImSNF8brFSfPHe5kb/qzkGIwUr/KRouaRYK8WLWZh/Mbl9xwREwhDSxWJSOdihSE0WWoaqSMtpaR99rDDCsD3mdJqfu0aPIlREupTZRzlrmztXU0eS3949YW+ywdTRvykaMNgOW2Q4saYP5j/niKbRW6GiDnaLV2A38X/HW80+trrsjwJr9tjTKVFyikf6s/3gzyiTp11ivSkwIY2b3hutjYn7OfTDo",
        #'__EVENTVALIDATION':"HqVo2xHk04clYwnBposXbZGhbIr181A7RbyeZv74Cia7rXSKmpOpbeSnn3XXnoDJKRxMK0W9nxKZFfkNje+P/K7gE5HVjHJr9Gr0Gs46TntzKDsvzyii8jZ7e0fdZgQCJKoXxQNgR2vNkWqChKcEldBuMHCOgJRqCNCF/JPFKpdKZoIWr7GU8rhzwLijf/Gkm+FuTULs/fl2HHK6Z1QQEozzEHFsDwzl0G4IiN//eNYfHuUBXKZ3wdZzPqG0s53WHEuSBzhqBC9AtCJOs4ZZhdtwFh8iyTJ4PlsLP9DLHYHRCOAd72UO0UH8gT7gAkKVo1I4L540DilowOR9SttH7MM/oOs9qhKlnG61FgqkYGW8zGzF/yNEXO+beVAK1RVvuO+FDnuq/g36TRnUieei5GpAZ+96CSoCIxykdvHx8R+smTNF/5erlowV4ci+tcI7", 
        '__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED':"", 
        '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR':"85862B00",
        '__VIEWSTATE':"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", 
        #'__VIEWSTATE':"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", 
        '__LASTFOCUS':"", 
        '__EVENTARGUMENT':"", 
        '__EVENTTARGET':"", 
        'ctl00_MainContent_ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField':";;AjaxControlToolkit,+Version=4.1.51116.0,+Culture=neutral,+PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e:en-US:fd384f95-1b49-47cf-9b47-2fa2a921a36a:475a4ef5:addc6819:5546a2b:d2e10b12:effe2a26:37e2e5c9:5a682656:c7029a2:e9e598a9"},method='POST',cookies = cookies1)

    def parse1(self, response):
        path1 = "id('Panel1')"
        value1 = response.xpath(path1).extract_first()[:574]
        print(value1)
```